# using int pointer in multiple couts

Tags: c++, pointers, segmentation-fault, cout, norton

I'm quite new to the world of pointers in C/C++ so this may be quite an easy question for you:

The following C++-Code works normally

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int theInt = 1337;
    int & theReference = theInt;
    int * thePointer = &theInt;

    std::cout << "int: " << theInt << "\n";
    std::cout << "referenz: " << theReference << "\n";
    std::cout << "pointer: " << *thePointer << "\n";
    std::cout << "pointer: " << *thePointer << "\n";

    //std::cout << "foo" << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

but stops working when changing

```
//std::cout << "foo" << "\n";
```

to

```
std::cout << "foo" << "\n";
```

.

By "stops working" I mean: "is blocked by my norton security as a potential threat" (resulting in a return code of "0x76F531AF" if this is any help). Since norton normally doesn't interfere withe my programming I assume the double use of the int pointer in cout somehow results in a segfault...

Thx for your help!

PS:

I use Code::Blocks on Windows 8.1 with the GCC compiler and GDB debugger from TDM-GCC (version 4.7.1, 32 bit).

EDIT: removed deletion of pointer -> problem remains.

Comment: `delete thePointer` is only necessary when you did `int *thePointer = new int` so please remove it

Comment: I deleted  the line, the problem remains.

Comment: Are you perhaps running an old version of your output binary by any chance?  Did you check Release/Debug config etc?  Does your IDE have "clean" command?  I'm asking this because there is nothing wrong with your code after you removed `delete thePointer`.

Comment: "is blocked by my norton security as a potential threat" Since this translates to "why is software X a piece of junk", this is really of topic. What do you expect us to tell you? You already know that the particular install of Norton Security you've got is useless junk. You can endure the pain and keep using it, or get rid of it. Your choice.

Comment: @KubaOber Actually I believed nortons intervention to be a sign of pointers going astray, so it was not really about: "Why does norton not work correctly".

Comment: Given that trapping of page faults and other exceptions is a valid programming technique, if Norton tripped over such things by design, it'd never let you do anything on your system. Anyway, get rid of that piece of crap and don't do things that will introduce malware on your system.

Answer (score 0):

You can only `delete` objects created on the heap (using `new` or C-style `malloc` and such).

```
// allocate on the heap
int *intOnTheHeap = new int;

// do some stuff with it
*intOnTheHeap = 0;
(*intOnTheHeap)++;
std::cout << *intOnTheHeap << std::endl;

// deallocate
delete intOnTheHeap;
```

If you take a pointer to a local variable, it will point to an entry on the stack. You don't need to and shouldn't deallocate that memory yourself. The memory is "freed" by changing the stackpointer automatically when your variable runs out of scope (at the end of the function).

```
void myFunction() {
    int localVariable;
    int *pointerToLocalVariable = &localVariable;

    // forbidden and unnecessary:
    //delete pointerToLocalVariable;

    // here (end of the block) the memory on the stack
    // will be freed automatically
}
```

Comment: Thx! I changed this part, but the problem still remains.

Comment: @MtDoom I don't know about Norton, but apart from the `delete` your code is perfectly fine. There certainly isn't any segmentation fault.

Comment: looks like norton is the only real issue here. Should I change the flags and title of the question or do I simply mark my own answer ("Its all norton's fault") as a solution and do nothing more about it?

Answer (score 0):

Since I got the same error after Norton-Interception in totally different contexts, this seems to be a case of Code::Blocks Norton incompatibility.